# Renaming the output file name from ffmpeg when using find and xargs

Tags: bash, file, find, rename, xargs

I am trying to rename the output files that are coming out of ffmpeg processes that I have spawned using find and xargs. I have a directory of files that I would like to convert to a certain format and all those files should ultimately be named .mov. So I am filtering out .mp4 & .mov files and then using xargs to pass it on to ffmpeg.

Suppose there are files such as abc.mp4, abcd.mp4, abcde.mp3, bcd.mov etc in the current working dir and then I am doing something like this to filter out just the mp4 and mov files and pass it on to ffmpeg for encoding:

`find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -o  -name "*.mov" | xargs -n 1 -p 5 -I '{}' ffmpeg -i '{}' ....... $PWD/{}"_h264.mov"`

This will do what I want ffmpeg to do but it will name the files like

abc.mp4_h264.mov,abcd.mp4_h264.mov,bcd.mov_h264.mov

What I would ideally like to achieve is to name the output files as

abc_h264.mov,abcd_h264.mov,bcd_h264.mov

I am not getting any sparks in my brain on how to do that at the place where I specify the output files of ffmpeg. I know that I can call basename command using xargs like this

`find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -o  -name "*.mov" | xargs -n 1 basename | rev | cut -d . -f 2 | rev`

and extract the filename without the extension but if i use that then how can I pass it on to ffmpeg as the input file because it would have lost the extension when it comes out of xargs and ffmpeg will throw an error.

Could anyone help me achieve this in one go where I can specify what 'basename' is doing but where I am specifying the output file name of ffmpeg please?

Thanks very much for any help that you can provide. Really appreciate the community.

Comment: better to make a small script that does all the processing of input vs output names and then calls `ffmpeg` with the corrected arguments. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mov" | xargs -I {} -n 1 -P 5 bash -c 'org="{}"; new="$PWD/${org%.*}_h264.mov"; ffmpeg -i "$org" {options} "$new"'
```

But it is not efficient for spawning `bash` command as a subprocess
multiple times. If you do not have a specific reason to use `find`
and `xargs`, it will be simpler to say:

```
for org in *.mp4 *.mov; do
    new="$PWD/${org%.*}_h264.mov"
    ffmpeg -i "$org" {options} "$new"
done
```

Comment: My Man! This solves the problem. I thank you very much for expanding my understanding of xargs. I agree that using a for loop is a much simpler way to do this. I just wanted to process a few files like batch process because I have the power available for it at my disposal rather than go through it one file at a time. 

Thanks very much for the help.